# Foreignkey Field with automcomplete

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Taking the Django tutorial as an example, Each Poll have multiple Choices. 
This is the from the tutorial in the admin form with a slightly changes (remove the vote to appear in the form and limit the choices to 5)

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
   fieldsets = [
        (Choices,     {'fields': ['choice']}),
            ]
    model = Choice
    max_num = 5

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

So this can add 5 max choices in a poll and each choice is insert via a text input field.
What I want to do is, how can I insert the choices via single text input field with js autocomplete feature, just like the tags system in this SO when create a question.

I can deal with the js part, what I really don't know how can I render the field and save the data. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom (Model)Form and Widget and [extending the admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) with an ajax endpoint. Have a look at [django-taggit-autosuggest](https://bitbucket.org/fabian/django-taggit-autosuggest), which does exactly this for the django-taggit library.

Comment: Seem this is what i needed! But is there any documentation out there? Because I can't find it. I like to know how to limit the numbers of tags and adding suggestions keyword externally...etc

Comment: You can simply use the form clean methods and return the form.errors with an error state instead of an ok state with succes message in your ajax call(s).

Comment: Although I didn't use the django-taggit-autosuggest,but I do use the taggit and combine with jquery plugin and it works like a charm. Your answer inspire me a lot, so I will take it as the answer. Thanks